# How to do image url validation in excel 2016?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to get reported Valid or invalid in excel if an image URL gives a 404 error? 
Without opening each image? eg checking header for 404?
 here's some snippets I've tried

```
Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
    Dim Request As Object
    Dim ff As Integer
    Dim rc As Variant

    On Error GoTo EndNow
    Set Request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    With Request
      .Open "GET", url, False
      .Send
      rc = .StatusText
    End With
    Set Request = Nothing
    If rc = "OK" Then URLExists = True

    Exit Function
EndNow:
End Function
```

```
Public Function IsURLGood(url As String) As Boolean
    Dim request As New WinHttpRequest

    On Error GoTo IsURLGoodError
    request.Open "HEAD", url
    request.Send
    If request.Status = 200 Then
        IsURLGood = True
    Else
        IsURLGood = False
    End If
    Exit Function

IsURLGoodError:
    IsURLGood = False
End Function
```

These report on all URLS, for me, TRUE. When I check, for example

```
http://www.bangallawebservices.com/images/BWA22055.jpg
```

these are definitely giving undesired results for return values, the above image is an example of the 404 error that's being counted as a valid URL in excel via these code snippets.

I've also tried the free demo of the Office PowerUp addin, with `pwrISBROKENURL` which returned all false (not broken) when some are in fact broken. Excel is granted full access to internet through firewall.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HU99-fXNV40

Comment: Well, the snippets work fine for me on the examples you've provided.

Comment: "I tried some stuff but nothing worked" is typically not a good approach when posting here.  Including the actual code you tried, along with a description of what happened when you ran it will get you more suggestions and help.

Comment: That wasn't me, but that edit's not going to improve your chances...  There's a pretty good answer here: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/567315-check-if-url-exists-so-then-return-true.html   Maybe change the GET to HEAD, since you don't really need to actually download the image.

Comment: ...or look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064315/excel-vba-script-to-find-404-errors-in-a-list-of-urls/36065167#36065167

Comment: Post is edited now to share details, and code examples used, including 404 image link. That is actually one of the tutorials and code snippets I've attempted already @TimWilliams I just finished a college class in excel, we didn't cover very much in VBA, just the basics for seeing macro codes after they are recorded.

Comment: I just plugged your sample url into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542790/msxml2-xmlhttp-request-to-validate-entered-url-in-asp-classic) and it reported a 404 error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me.  It doesn't return a boolean but the actual Status or the error description if there is one during execution:

```
Public Function IsURLGood(url As String)
    Dim request As Object
    Set request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    On Error GoTo haveError
    With request
        .Open "HEAD", url
        .Send
        IsURLGood = .Status
    End With
    Exit Function
haveError:
    IsURLGood = Err.Description
End Function
```

Quick test:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Instead of running it as a UDF you can do this:

```
Sub ProcessUrls()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c in Activesheet.Range("A1:A20000").Cells
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = IsURLGood(c.Value) 'put result in ColB
    Next c
End sub
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much @TimWilliams! [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/eSUn4ta.png)

Comment: @LevyImage - If you have 30K rows (per your original post) then you are going to want to make that WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 **static** like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/16978/when-to-use-a-static-variable#t=20170628234448361758).

Comment: In addition/alternatively to suggestion from @Jeeped, consider not using a UDF but a Sub instead, to ensure you're only running each check once.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to basically rasterize the column used with this formula to just leave behind the values? When I copy/paste values only, it freezes excel (over 20K rows). If I try to save as a text based file type like CSV, excel also freezes. I'll read up on what the difference between UDF and Sub, again I'm new to VB, thank you.